# Equation with three exponential levels

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, systems-of-equations, lambert-w

I am trying to solve the following equation :
$$ a^{(\frac{\ln x}{1+\ln x})} + \frac{\ln a}{1+ \ln x} + \ln(\frac{\ln a}{1+ \ln x}) = b$$ 
with $a$ and $b$ two fixed real numbers.

I want to find $x$ or at least upper/lower bounds for $x$.

As suggested in the comments : let $u=\frac{\ln a}{1+ \ln x}$, since $\frac{\ln x}{1+\ln x}=1-\frac{u}{\ln a}$ we can rewrite this equation into :
$$ a^{(1-\frac{u}{\ln a})} + u + \ln u = b$$

I think that one possibility could be to use the $W$  [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). But I could not succeed in rewriting my equation in order to use the usual identities and properties of $W$.

Does anybody have an idea on how to tackle this problem ?

Many thanks, Luz

Comment: You should substitute $u=\frac{\ln(a)}{1+\ln(x)}$ to make your expression a little bit more compact. First, try to solve for $u$. The additional complexity does not aid you in finding a solution. Note, that the power of the first term is equal to $1-u/\ln(a)$. You should also give the domain for $a$ and $b$.

Comment: what is $\log$ here? $$\ln(x)$$

Comment: or the first Exponent of $a$ is $$\frac{\log(a)}{1+\log(x)}$$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*---  expanded  ---*
If you do the following substitution
$$
\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  0 < \ln a = c \hfill \\
  0 < \frac{{\ln a}}
{{1 + \ln x}} = 1 + z \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.
$$
you get

> $$
> \left\{ \begin{gathered}
>   c = \ln a\quad \left| {\;0 < c} \right. \hfill \\
>   e^{\,c - 1 - z}  + 1 + z + \ln \left( {1 + z} \right) = b\quad \left| {\; - 1 < z} \right. \hfill \\
>   x = e^{\,c\,/\,\left( {1 + z} \right) - 1} \quad \left| {\;0 < x} \right. \hfill \\ 
> \end{gathered}  \right.
> $$

If you draw $h(z,c) = e^{\,c - 1 - z}  + 1 + z + \ln \left( {1 + z} \right)$ you can see that it has a quite a manageable behaviour.
However, while for low values of $c$ the function is monotonically increasing, for higher values of $c$ instead 
the function is not monotone and has a maximum and a minimum for the stated range of $z$.
In this case, if $b$ is below the minimum or above the maximum you have one solution, while if it is in between you have three solutions.
[image: Log_di_Log]

Now, which is the better strategy to follow in order to solve $h(z,c)=b$ depends on what actually is you goal 
(are going to solve a few cases *"by hand"*, or are you looking for a general algorithm),
whether the $c$ or $x$ range is limited, etc.

For a "by hand" resolution I would proceed in general as follows.

1. given $c$, draw a graph of $h(z,c)$, place the $b$ level and determine if you have any solution, one, or three, and get
   an estimate $z_0$ of the relative solutions;
2. start from a chosen estimate $z_0$ and perform the Newton-Raphson method on $g(z,c)=h(z,c)-b$;
3. once you get a $z_k$ *enough* near to $z_{k-1}$ check the value of $g(z_{k},c)$
   to be near $0$, and in case determine a $z^{*}_{k}$ for which $g$ is close to $0$
   but with opposite sign.
4. compute $x(z_{k},c)$ and $x(z^{*}_{k},c)$ and valuate if the difference is enough close
   for $x_{sol}$ to be in between (you can orientate yourself by $\left| {\Delta x} \right| \cong e^{\,c\,/\,\left( {1 + z_k } \right) - 1} \left| {z_k  - z_{k - 1} } \right| \cong e^{\,c\,/\,\left( {1 + z_k } \right) - 1} \left| {z_k  - z^* _{k - 1} } \right|$);
5. if the $b$ value is such that in step 1) it is difficult to discriminate  whether there are or not 
   solutions, then you may need to compute first the $z_{min/max}$ through N-R applied to 
   $$
   \frac{\partial }
   {{\partial z}}h(z,c) =  - e^{\,c - 1 - z}  + \frac{{2 + z}}
   {{1 + z}} = 0
   $$
   and then compute whether or not $b$ is above\below $h_{min/max}$.

Comment: Thanks :-) Let $f(x)=e^{c-1-z}+1+z+\ln(1+z)-b$ with $z=\frac{\ln a}{1+\ln x}-1$ we want $x_{sol}$ such that $f(x_{sol})=0$. The derivative is $f'(x)=-z'e^{c-1-z} + z' + \frac{z'}{1+z}$ where $z'=-\frac{\ln a}{x \ln^2 x}$. We get the Newton expansion $x_{k+1}=x_k - \frac{f(x_k)}{f'(x_k)}$ which converges to the optimal solution $x_{sol}$. Since each formula $x_k$ depends on $x_0$ $a$ and $b$ we write them $x_k(x_0, a, b)$. I want to find the $k$ for which the formula $x_k(x_0, a, b)$ approximates $x_{sol}$ according to some precision $p(x_0,a,b)$ (for example : $p(x_0,a,b)$ digits after comma).

Comment: Is that the good method for what I want to do ? If so, (1) how can I compute the precision $p(x_0,a,b)$, (2) does there exists a common agreement about the concept of "reasonable precision" and (3) how should I choose the $k$ for which the precision is considered "reasonable" ? Maybe I should post a new question about all that ?

Comment: Forget for a moment about $x$, and just work on $z$. After you find $z_k$ with Newton-Raphson, $g(z_{k})$ will tell you how far you are from $0$. And you should be able to estimate an interval for $z_{sol}$, and from this to go back to an interval for $x_{sol}$. But before applying N-R method, you shall determine where $g(z)$ is **monotone**, which depends on $c$. I will add some more details in my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I was initially looking for close form formulas for bounding $x_{sol}$ but I think it is too ambitious. I did not know that the equation I was trying to solve was that complicated. Your method to find by hand an approximation of $x_{sol}$ is enough at this time for me. And as this method is quite generic, I will use it in other similar situations involving high complexity equations. Thanks again :-)

Comment: @Luz: a) glad that it helps  b) sorry, amended for No. of sol. : there is at least 1 sol.  c) perhaps, if you limit yourself to the larger sol. you may find some formula to bound $x_{sol}$, since the exp term decays; presently I did not find a satisfactory one because of the $\log$ term: for a satisfactory one you always need a previous estimate .